# Writing a loop to create sorted subsets of larger dataframes

Tags: r, loops, sorting

I'd like to extract a number of sorted rows from a larger matrix. Here's an example:

```
n.cols = 5
n.rows = 10

test.matrix <- matrix(runif(n.cols*n.rows), ncol = n.cols)
```

Suppose I'd like a matrix of the rows for which the second column has the three highest values. I can accomplish this with the `data.table` package, like so:

```
require(data.table)
test.dt = data.table(test.matrix)

var1.sort = test.dt[,.SD[order(V2,decreasing=TRUE)[1:3]]]
```

which produces `var1.sort` containing

```
          V1        V2         V3         V4         V5
1: 0.6551792 0.9226611 0.86754419 0.43032372 0.03408796
2: 0.9701061 0.9069784 0.64011847 0.07069091 0.27211697
3: 0.4633638 0.8198762 0.01301018 0.69369268 0.62023243
```

which is exactly what I would like. Great. Suppose now that I'd like to write a loop so that I can do a similar process for a number of different columns. I think this should be accomplished for the first and third columns by

```
sort.list = list("V1", "V3")

for (n in sort.list) {
  (n).list = test.dt[,.SD[order((n),decreasing=TRUE)[1:3]]]
}
```

But as you might guess, it is not. I have tried several variations on this so I don't have a specific error message that's hanging me up. Rather I am stuck on the conceptual problem: how can I extract a number of sorted rows from a larger matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
lapply(c('V1','V3'),function(cn) test.dt[order(test.dt[,cn,with=F],decreasing=T)[1:3]]);
## [[1]]
##           V1        V2         V3        V4        V5
## 1: 0.9949206 0.3704618 0.36016581 0.5348180 0.3464949
## 2: 0.9108933 0.0608218 0.03951099 0.1801457 0.8832705
## 3: 0.8157573 0.3232237 0.01518571 0.8879577 0.7788657
##
## [[2]]
##            V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
## 1: 0.04260936 0.8815819 0.9903040 0.3934099 0.8170457
## 2: 0.63491716 0.1231150 0.8113234 0.3040940 0.5464126
## 3: 0.46112893 0.6895573 0.6498408 0.5549647 0.7815175
##
```

It first extracts the complete column using the parameterized column name `cn` by passing it with the `with=F` variation for the `j` argument:

```
test.dt[,cn,with=F]
```

Actually, if you prefer, a shorter alternative that uses base R syntax is:

```
test.dt[[cn]]
```

Then it calls `order()` on that, producing the required sort order, and indexes out the first three sorted indexes with `[1:3]`. Finally it extracts those rows from the original data.table object by indexing it using the `i` argument.

---

If you really want an explicit for-loop:

```
cns <- c('V1','V3');
res <- list();
for (cn in cns) res[[cn]] <- test.dt[order(test.dt[,cn,with=F],decreasing=T)[1:3]];
res;
## $V1
##           V1        V2         V3        V4        V5
## 1: 0.9949206 0.3704618 0.36016581 0.5348180 0.3464949
## 2: 0.9108933 0.0608218 0.03951099 0.1801457 0.8832705
## 3: 0.8157573 0.3232237 0.01518571 0.8879577 0.7788657
##
## $V3
##            V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
## 1: 0.04260936 0.8815819 0.9903040 0.3934099 0.8170457
## 2: 0.63491716 0.1231150 0.8113234 0.3040940 0.5464126
## 3: 0.46112893 0.6895573 0.6498408 0.5549647 0.7815175
##
```

Comment: Here's a similar option: `lapply(cns, function(x){ setorderv(test.dt, x, order=-1); head(test.dt, 3) })`. It has the side effect of sorting the data, though.